# How to cross-filter joined reports?

Tags: joined-reports, reporting, cross-filter

As of Summer '12, joined reports do not support cross filters and I'm wondering if there is a way to work around it.

Example:
I have a custom objects for Events, Events Attended, and Work History.  Events Attended joins an Account to an Event via Master-Detail relationships (like a simple join table.)  Events Attended and Work History are related lists on Accounts.  I can create a joined report to show me which events a person has attended and retrieve their previous employers, but I only want to see results for people who attended Event A.  If I filter the Events Attended block on Event A, I still get records for all Accounts.

Is there a way to effectively cross filter this to hide those Accounts that did not attend Event A?  Would I need a workflow or trigger to just copy every Event name into a field on the Account and filter on that?

**Edit**
To be clear, what I am trying to do is for a given subset of Accounts (e.g. attended a specific event) retrieve fields from their related Opportunities and Work History (Work History being a related list on Accounts.)

The equivalent SQL would be

```
SELECT *
FROM Accounts [A]
INNER JOIN Events_Attended [EA]
  ON EA.AccountId = A.AccountId
INNER JOIN Work_History [WH]
  ON WH.AccountId = A.AccountId
INNER JOIN Opportunity [O]
  ON O.AccountId = A.AccountId
WHERE EA.EventName = "MyEvent"
```

Comment: how are you even tracking which accounts attended an event? Right now you can only add multiple contacts to an event not multiple accounts.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain the relationships.  These are custom objects, with Events Attended relating Accounts to Events (there is one Master-Detail from E.A. to Account and one Master-Detail from E.A. to Event.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with Premier Support today and they confirmed I could not do what I wanted since each piece of a joined report is pulled separately.  Currently, the best solution is to add a custom field to the Account and filter based on that.

Comment: is the custom field needs to be a related list? I guess so

Comment: No, it may just be a text field for filtering, and only for the one user that needs it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom report types and add there if you want the relationship object A with or without records related to object B. then you don't need to create a filter anymore.

Sven

[image: Custom report types]

Comment: I will check that out this today.