# Report for two parents that look up same child object

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have a question similar to [Reports for two lookup objects that relate to a parent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/700/reports-for-two-lookup-objects-that-relate-to-a-parent).

I have an two objects (`Payable Invoice` and `Cash Entry`) which look up the same child (`Transaction`).

I'd like to report on them to be able to link `Payable Invoices` with `Cash Entries`. How could I do that? Joined reports don't seem to allow Transaction's attributes to be used for joining because they don't belong to both objects.

[image: Object graph]

Comment: So you want your report to only show Payable Invoices whose Transactions have at least one Cash Entry? Can you provide a small sample of what the report should like?

Comment: @MikeChale Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, with the first being to check "Allow Reports" when you create the custom objects. When you create the objects this way Salesforce will generate reports of *Payable Invoices with Transactions and Cash Entries* and *Cash Entries with Transactions and Payable Invoices*.

The second method will require a `Custom Report Type` and `Cross Filters`.

1. Create a CRT based on either `Cash Entry` or `Payable Invoice` and
   then select `Transaction` as a child object. Let's assume you made it based on `Payable Invoice`.
2. Create a report on your new type.
3. Add a Cross Filter and set it to `Payable Invoices with Transactions`.
4. Click add a Transactions Filter for `Cash Entry not equal to (blank)`

[image]